# I cannot receive response in call using retrofit2 using java in android cannot parse response in model

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, retrofit2

this is a one element array. I cannot receive it in call using retrofit2 using java in android 
i am using this model

```
    @SerializedName("timelineitems")
    public List<HashMap<String,Data>> data;

    public class Data{

            @SerializedName("new_daily_cases")
            public String new_cases;

    }
```

but in the last line found  object string

```
            "stat": "ok"
```

this line make the call run throw on failure

```
"timelineitems":[
{
    "4/17/20": {
                "new_daily_cases": 150,
                "new_daily_deaths": 16,
                "total_cases": 2418,
                "total_recoveries": 65,
                "total_deaths": 364
            },
            "4/18/20": {
                "new_daily_cases": 116,
                "new_daily_deaths": 3,
                "total_cases": 2534,
                "total_recoveries": 65,
                "total_deaths": 367
            },
            "stat": "ok"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: It's not a valid JSON

Comment: Solved you can see the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is the model i use to solve the problem 
public class Model{

```
@SerializedName("timelineitems")
public List<HashMap<String,Object>> data;

public class Data{

    @SerializedName("new_daily_cases")
    public String new_cases;
    @SerializedName("new_daily_deaths")
    public String new_daily_deaths;
    @SerializedName("total_cases")
    public String total_cases;
    @SerializedName("total_recoveries")
    public String total_recoveries;
    @SerializedName("total_deaths")
    public String total_deaths;

}
```

}

then i use this code to get my data

try {         Model resource=response.body();

```
                   HashMap<String,Object>data=resource.data.get(0);

                    Gson g = new Gson();
                    Data inf = g.fromJson(g.toJson(resource.data.get(0).get(date0)), Data.class);



                }catch (NullPointerException e){
                   =
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No data available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```